# Why does AVAssetExportSession produce an empty file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to export a .mov file from a source video created by UIImagePickerController. The problem is that the output file AVAssetExportSession creates is only 668 bytes. Why is it failing? my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *imagePickerVideoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *filename = @"vid1.mov";

    AVAsset *video = [AVAsset assetWithURL:imagePickerVideoURL];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession
      = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:video presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.outputURL = [pathToSavedVideosDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    NSLog(@"processing video...: %@", exportSession);
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                       NSLog(@"done processing video!");
                   }];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to guess it's because `exportSession` was not retained in memory, thus gets killed after the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` completes (before the export session completion handler runs).

Store `exportSession` to a `@property` or change your completion handler to copy a reference to `exportSession` like so:

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
       if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
       {
           NSLog(@"done processing video!");
       }
}];
```

Comment: It's a good guess but I don't think that's the problem. I use other asynchronous methods, such as network calls, and they don't auto-release themselves in mid-operation even if they aren't assigned to a (strong) property.

Comment: Have you tried it anyway? I've seen this bug before and I'm 80% sure this is your problem.

Comment: BTW, the reasoning that "other asynchronous methods don't auto-release themselves, so this one shouldn't too" is something you need to be careful of. Network calls only work that way because they are usually retained by backing `NSOperation`s so they don't die until they complete (or fail).

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll definitely try it out.

Answer (score 3):

you need to write down steps for video file with AVAssetExportSession..

Start with `Asset`
Put your fileURL

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
```

Create `AVMutableComposition`

```
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)    ofTrack:clipVideoTrack  atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

Create `AVMutableVideoComposition` with Aniamtion layer if you want

```
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] retain];
    videoComp.renderSize = CGSizeMake(videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComp.renderScale = 1.0;
    videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Animation layer are here if you need otherwise pass `nil`.

```
CGSize videoSize = [videoAsset naturalSize];

//layer mixing
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
```

Add aniamtion to your selected layer which you need to add as `sublayer` in `parentLayer`

Add instruction in video composition with mention animation layer and time duration.

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];
```

Now creating `AVAssetExportSession` with use of `AVMutableComposition` and `AVMutableVideoComposition`

```
_assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
_assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;
```

//Create tmepory path for exported video file. .m4a would be preferred extension for AVFoundation.

```
NSString *videoName = @"demo.m4a";
NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}
```

Add url in Export session and some required property.

```
_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie; 
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
_assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
```

Start Export session and perform action when you will get complete message.

```
[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {
     switch (_assetExport.status)
     {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
             NSLog(@"Unknown");
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
             NSLog(@"Exporting");
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog(@"exporting failed");
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             NSLog(@"exporting completed");
             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(completeVideoExport) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             NSLog(@"export cancelled");
             break;
     }
     _assetExport = nil;
     [_assetExport release];
 }       
 ];
```

if you need any more let me know..

Comment: thank you for code. My code initial AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction error. Now I know how to do it. :P

Answer (score 1):

The exportSession has an "error" property that you can check to determine what the error is. A lot of times the errors aren't particularly helpful but it's at least a place to start.

Note that I've seen issues with .mov files, where codecs in them aren't supported by AVFoundation.

Answer (score 1):

For **debugging**, try this...

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 NSLog(@"exportSessionMetaData:%@", exportSession.metadata);

                 if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted){
                     NSError *dataReadingError = nil;
                     NSData *videoData = nil;
                     videoData = 
                                [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[pathToSavedVideosDirectory  
                                                       URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

                                                       options:NSDataReadingMapped 
                                                         error:&dataReadingError];
                     if (videoData != nil) {
                         // You got video data, do you work here...
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"Failed to load the video data. ERROR:%@", dataReadingError);
                     }
                 }
             });
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out TSLibraryImport - the import code works.

Comment: Can it be used for UIImagePicker instead of the iPod library?

Comment: TSLibrary (to extract an MPS) pulls an Asset from the library and saves it as a .MOV...image picker will not let you save it as a video as far as I know...So use the TSLibrary import code which pulls an asset and saves it as a movie, to save your movie.  For flat pictures just use the saveAsJpeg function passing UIImage as a parameter.  It works.

Comment: what is MPS? And the video file I want to work with is created by uiimagepicker...its not in the library.

Comment: MP3 sorry typo.  Yeah but I dont think you can get the image data. I havent tried.  You can get a UIImage.  but I dont know that you can save a video asset from what you get from UIImagePicker.  Could be wrong havent tried.  But TSLibrary import shows how to get a video and store it.